# Why does this IPTables command create 4 entries?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, firewall

When I executed this IPTables command: 
`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -s localhost -d localhost -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -L` shows:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            localhost            tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            localhost            tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            localhost            tcp dpt:9080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            localhost            tcp dpt:9080
```

Why four times? I mean, it does what I want, but why does it need to show four times?

**edit:**
All of the commands entered to reproduce this (multiple times) on my side are:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.99.169.167/32 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

**iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -d localhost -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT**

**iptables -A INPUT -s localhost -d localhost -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9081 -j ACCEPT**

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: FYI: you may want to include the `-v` option.  I doubt it applies to your case, but without the `-v` option some information is not displayed as part of the list.  I usually use `iptables -vnL`.

Comment: @Zoredache: Thank you! I'm using that now, it helps a lot actually!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't, unless there is a bug.  However, `iptables -A` is not idempotent, and if you run it multiple times (or run a redundant `iptables -A` command against an existing or loaded configuration), it will add the rule again whether or not it is an exact duplicate of a dispositive rule.

Another thing that might be happening is that resolution gives multiple results for the name `localhost`.  This is very rare because best practice dictates against using names in iptables commands.  You can inspect your `/etc/hosts` file to determine this, or you can use `iptables -nL` to show what the IPs are.  In such a case, yes, it does need to add multiple rules for your request (since in this particular case it resolves and expands the names at insertion time), and you should probably be explicitly specifying `127.0.0.1` if that is what you want.

Comment: Please see my edit to see all the commands entered into a fresh iptables. As you can see, I only enter each command once and, as far as I know, none of them are redundant.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the unusual behaviour that results when people do this inadvisable thing.  Enjoy.

Comment: What inadvisable thing? Sorry, I'm slightly a dunce at this :) Is it inadvisable to use 127.0.0.1 in IPTables?

Comment: Ah! Both my IPv6 and IPv4 addresses were resolving for localhost, and -s and -d added their own equaling 4 total entries. Thank you for your help :) I will use specific numbers from now on!!